# Different benchmarks for string manipulation in C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, string

I have two very simple code in C++ and C#
in c#

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 100000; counter ++)
{
    String a = "";
    a = "xyz";
    a = a + 'd';
    a = a + 'c';
    a = a + 'h';
}
```

in c++

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 100000; counter ++)
{
    string a = "";
    a.append("xyz");
    a = a + 'd';
    a = a + 'c';
    a = a + 'h';
}
```

the strange thing is the c# code took 1/20 time for execution than the c++ code.
could you please help me to find why this happened? and how can I change my c++ code to become faster.

Comment: Is it just me or is `a = "xyz"` and `a.append("xyz")` not semantically equivalent?

Comment: they are different but but when a = "" they work the same.

Comment: @MasoudHabibi - the result is the same, but I'm pretty sure the implementation is rather different (and most probably `append` is slower than `operator=`). Try with `operator=`. Also, how you compile your code?

Comment: Both compiled with visual studio 2010 compilers. it is imposible to write a = "xyz" in c++. it gave a compile error

Comment: @MasoudHabibi: It should work, [string& operator= ( const char* s );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) is defined, as is [string ( const char * s );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

Comment: @MasoudHabibi - this can't be true, you _can_ write `a="xyz"`, as in your case `a` is `std::string`.

Comment: @KirilKirov: yes you are right. the last time I tried to do that with a pointer so it fails. i thought it is a same situation

Comment: @Masoud Habibi: If you're strill struggling with pointers, you probably should not be benchmarking C++.

Comment: I doubt this happens. Are you compiling with optimizations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably a quirk of the implementations. For example, one optimizer might have figured out that the result of the operations isn't used. Or one might happen to allocate a string large enough to add three extra characters without reallocating while the other didn't. Or it could be a million other things.

Benchmarking with "toy" code really isn't helpful. I wouldn't assume the results apply to any realistic situation.

There are so many obvious optimizations to this code, for example:

```
string a;
for (int counter = 0; counter < 100000; counter ++)
{
    a = "xyz";
    a.append(1, 'd');
    a.append(1, 'c');
    a.append(1, 'h');
}
```

That may make a huge difference by reusing the buffer and avoiding extra allocate/copy/free cycles.

Comment: It is a real case. it is a long code so I made a brief of it and copied here. I think there should be a difference between c++ string and c# string. I want to handle my string in c++ faster. It should be possible to do it in some way. because codes in c++ if well written should have at least the same speed as c# codes

Comment: Right, but this code is very far from well-written. You should never use `a = a + x;` because that requires creating an extra allocate/copy/free cycle to hold `a + x`.

Comment: could you please give me a minute to try that?

Comment: I have a same efficiency problem in vector.push_back in C++ and List.Add in C#. could you please help me. it seems as I read in internet pus_back do allocate/copy/free cycle. is there a way to push without these?

Comment: @MasoudHabibi: There's no one right way to do it. It depends on the actual code. It may be cheaper to default construct the object in the vector and then do `std::swap(myVector[index], myObject);` Or it may be better to default-construct the object in the vector and then do `myVector[index] = myObject`. Or `push_back` might be best. You have to look at the specifics. (But 99 times out of 100, there's no need to optimize this in realistic programs.)

Comment: but push_back is 20 times slower than .Add. I am really confused. I though c++ should be faster than C#. but it seems it is a lot slower

Comment: @MasoudHabibi: The real world is very often not as it "should" be. One wouldn't ordinarily expect the performance difference between C# and C++ to be more than 10%. That can easily be totally swamped by even the slightest algorithmic differences.

Comment: yes you said 10%. But in my case one of em is 20 times faster than the other. so I should have done something worng

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your code was so bad that rather than measuring the performance of the languages, you were measuring the algorithmic efficiency of their string classes. Say there are two car brands and one is 10% cheaper than the other. If you send out two savvy buyers to buy similar cars meeting similar requirements from both dealers, the one who goes to the cheaper dealer should pay 10% less. But if you send two loons who randomly pick things to buy, who knows which will pay more and which will pay less. They're so inefficient at shopping that it's down to happenstance.

Comment: I even did the reserve thing to completely avoid any unwanted overhead. but still my c++ code is slower than c# code. how code it happen?

Comment: It happens because you're measuring the algorithmic efficiency of the string classes over the specific operations you are doing. That has nothing to do with the efficiency of the languages. If you want to measure the efficiency of the languages, you will have to write your own code to do the same work in both languages, not assume that the two string implementations will do the same work. (Try writing your own string class that implements allocation, copying, and so on, the same on both platforms and then compare.)

Comment: yes in string case you are right. I wrote a non effiecient code and I got a lot worse time. but in vector push back case everything seems right.

Comment: Again, you're measuring the efficiency of the vector push algorithm. If you want to compare the two languages, you have to write the code whose efficiency you are measuring so that it is the same in both languages. Here's another analogy: You have two foremen, one very good, one very bad. If they both just say to a bunch of workers "build a house", the better foreman won't necessarily build a better house. But if the formen direct each step of the house building, then the better foreman will likely build a better house. Your code's just "build a house". Not much room for good code generation.

Comment: How can I access to implementation detail of .add in C#?

Answer (score 0):

For large string manipulation use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)